# Jenkins GUI Automaion script execution

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, execution

I am new to Jenkins. My query is 
What I am trying to achieve.

1) We have automation framework (GUI kindoff). Which will trigger UFT / Selenium Scripts.

2) I have installed Jenkins.

3) I need to run some batch commands which will execute UFT scripts via built in framework.

4) When running via command line I am able to trigger scripts (UFT).

5) From Jenkins I am not able to run GUI commands.(It should trigger my framework and start UFT script execution)

**Please note:**
Build is success. I am doing all this from Master Jenkins. no slave machine.

- Is it necessary to have slave machine to run GUI

I tried almost all settings by searching google.

Please help.

thanks in advance.
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webdriver in your selecium script thats requires UI to be success than you have to consider using Slave which will have UI support and you need to connect there via Xvnc or something similar

if you are using webdriver which does not require UI (for example google chrome headless) then there should be some miss configuration in jenkins side, therefor to help you figure it out you need to provide more details

Comment: Thank you very much. This plugin helped me to run GUI scripts. However, VBS file is not getting executed but this is fine for me.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to accept answer and upvote it ;)